# How do I run MacSpice on the Terminal?

Tags: spice, mac

Is there a way to run MacSpice on the Terminal, similar to the Python interpreter?

Comment: This is a very software related question, not sure if appropriate

Comment: Although it is electronic design software helping you change the way in which you open it is outside the domain of our site.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to install LTSpice IV into Wine, it is not graphically pleasing, but after hours of fiddling with MacSpice I got to say that LTSpice made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it from the terminal directly you must use it with in the application MacSpice. You can load it from the terminal by using the following command:

```
open /Applications/MacSpice.app
```

I suggest you do look at an alternative that has a graphical schematic capture to reduce the errors in your schematic, something like LTSpice or PSpice.